# Japanese long sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 他方、成績評価の甘い授業が高く評価されたり、人気取りに走る教師が出たりし、成績の安売りや大学教師のレベルダウンという弊害をもたらす恐れがある、などの反省意見もある.

I really don't understand this sentence meaning, anyone knows?

> On the other hand, by focusing on evaluating lessons which students weak(?), teacher who has popularity who cheapening grades

Can you give me advice how to understand Japanese long sentences? Although sometimes I know the meaning of each kanji and words but when it comes in a sentence, sometimes I don't get the main point of the sentence and becomes more ambiguous.

Comment: Hmm, did you mean to write レベルダウン perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure you know every word used?  "accepted bribes" is never said in the original, for instance.

Comment: its just my interpretation from this sentences 成績の安売りや大学教師のレベルダウンという弊害をもたらす恐れがある ->成績の安売 , i think that the teacher reduce the value of learning by making it easier for student to get good grades by maybe bribe(?) -> thats why i ask question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「[他方]{たほう}、[成績評価]{せいせきひょうか}の[甘]{あま}い[授業]{じゅぎょう}が[高]{たか}く[評価]{ひょうか}されたり、[人気取]{にんきと}りに[走]{はし}る[教師]{きょうし}が[出]{で}たりし、[成績]{せいせき}の[安売]{やすう}りや[大学教師]{だいがくきょうし}のレベルダウンという[弊害]{へいがい}をもたらす[恐]{おそ}れがある、などの[反省意見]{はんせいいけん}もある。」

As far as grammar and structure, this is actually a pretty straightforward-looking sentence with no 'tricks or traps'.  As long as you REALLY know the meaning of each word (***and have a feeling for them***), there should be no problem understanding the sentence.

The basic structure of this sentence is:

> The general statement: "On the other hand, there also are reflective opinions."  （「他方」 and 「などの反省意見もある」）

Just in case you did not realize, the rest of the sentence is only an 'explanation with examples' of that general statement.

↓

> An example of a possible negative effect leading to a reflective opinion.　（「成績の安売りや大学教師のレベルダウンという弊害をもたらす恐れがある」）

↓

> Two example causes to the possible negative effect above.　（「成績評価の甘い授業が高く評価されたり」 and 「人気取りに走る教師が出たりし」）

My own translation attempt:

> "On the other hand, there also exist some reflective opinions.  One such opinion is that because the classes (courses) where student evaluation is not strict could be rated highly (by the students), or because some instructors might blindly seek popularity, there is a fear that those events might bring a harmful influence such as easy grade bumping and the general decline in the standard of university instructors."

Comment: Now i understood but i think the problem for me is its hard for me to guess the subject and object from the sentence, and 評価 has meaning evaluation and also appreciation, by translating blindly the sentence : 成績評価の甘い授業が高く評価さ,  generous grading evaluation is evaluated high by ... ->how you know is rated highly by student(?) how you know the subject is student not school maybe(?) and why 評価 in this part mean rated and not evaluated (?)(?) since its passive i was confuse who is the doer and also 甘い really ambiguous to me at first(eng is my sec language so maybe my language a bit irritated to you)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newcomer just like you and I might make mistakes, so please wait for outside opinions before deciding whether you can trust my answer.

---

> 成績評価の甘い授業

Here 成績評価の甘い is a characteristic of 授業. 甘い is used in the sense of "generous". So all together it means:

> Teaching/lessons with generous grading.

---

> 成績の安売り

Here 安売り is used in a figurative sense, meaning that something becomes easy to get (not in terms of money!). So we have:

> "Cheapening" of grades. (it's getting a lot easier to get good grades)

---

About understanding long sentences. When something seems too complex, usually you need to break it down into smaller parts and try to see how they relate to each other. Look for clues, such as typical sentence connectors.

In your example 他方 obviously connects the previous sentence to this one. など…もある means "… like that also exist". Like what? Like what is described above, of course. So for now we have:

> 他方、「…」、などの反省意見もある.
>
> However, opinions like [...] also exist.

So now all that's left is to figure out the [...] part.

---

> 成績評価の甘い授業が高く評価されたり、人気取りに走る教師が出たりし、成績の安売りや大学教師のレベルダウンという弊害をもたらす恐れがある

Seems a bit intimidating at first but again, let's see how these three phrases separated by commas (let's call these phrases A, B, and C) are connected. Now, I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that both たり here mean that the situation keeps developing. So it's something like "if we have A, then (due to A) happens B, then (due to A and B) happens C". So if you can understand what A, B and C mean separately, you will be able to figure out the whole sentence now:

> However, opinions like "A causes B and then C" also exist.

Do you need help understanding these parts too?

Comment: 成績評価の甘い授業が高く評価されたり this means Teaching/lessons with generous grading -> this sentence has positive or negative meaning? 甘い really ambiguous to me.                                                                                                          人気取りに走る教師が出たりし、成績の安売りや大学教師 -> teacher who has popularity who reduce the value of learning by making it easier for student to get good grades (?)                                                                                  i dont understand what is the connection of first and second sentence?

Comment: I think 甘い just means that the teacher isn't very demanding, but doesn't say whether it's a good or a bad thing. But it can be used to criticize someone for being too soft, I wonder if that's the case here. To be honest I'm a bit confused by 人気取りに走る myself, it's a new expression to me. But after that it literally says: 成績の安売りや大学教師のレベルダウン ("cheapening" of grades and a "level down" of university teachers) という弊害をもたらす (it might bring these negative effects) 恐れがある (there is a risk that).

Comment: (横から失礼します。) Yes, calling someone or the way of doing something 「甘い」 (in the sense of "soft," "lenient," or "unthorough," etc.) is definitely more of an accusation than a compliment. 「Xに走る」 means "to turn to X," or "to resort to X ," the X often being some bad practice. 人気取りに走る教師 are teachers who try just to score with students (人気取り = "win popularity") by some petty, unprofessional means, caring less about the actual quality of their teaching.

Comment: So I think correlations  (more like causal relations) are like this : 「成績評価の甘い授業が高く評価されたり(A1) 、人気取りに走る教師が出たり(B1)し、成績の安売り(A2)や大学教師のレベルダウン(B2)という弊害をもたらす恐れがある」 where A1 (that classes with "generous" grading are rated high (by students, most likely) ) brings about A2 (the cheapening of grades) and B1 (some professors trying to win popularity with students) causes B2 (the "level-down" of (the teaching ability of) university professors.)

Comment: @goldhick how do you know who is the subject and object in this passive sentence? " 成績評価の甘い授業が高く評価されたり" first i thought that it was evaluated by the teacher(?), the correct one is rated high by student right? and 評価 meaning in this sentence is "evaluate" or "rated"?

Comment: Determining the grammatical subject is fairly easy. Look for the noun phrase that comes right before the subject marker "が", and we find "授業 ("class", here context suggests it's plural, so "classes" )", which is modified by "成績評価の甘い (generous in grading)". So we have the subject: **"classes (that are generous in grading)"**.

Comment: The verb phrase of the clause is "高く評価され(たり)" which is in passive voice and may be translated to **"be rated/evaluated high"**. (To my mind, "rate" and "evaluate" are not significantly different from each other, and they both fall within the meaning of "評価する". What so important distinctions do you see between them, that only one of them may be correct?)

Comment: The doer, by whom the classes are rated/evaluated high, however, is not mentioned explicitly, and can be reached only through inference. When we say that a class, given and conducted by a teacher, is rated/evaluated, it is usually supposed that the rating/evaluation is done by other than the teacher him/herself, so we can exclude the possibility of self-appraisal. Other teachers or some commission can be reasonably thought of, but remember that we are not talking about just any classes, but classes that are generous in grading.

Comment: Who, above all, can be assumed to favor such classes?: **The students.**

Comment: Or it could be the school chairman looking at the grades and thinking "wow, this teacher is really good, all his students are doing well". Or the school psychologist saying that it's important to reward the students with high grades so that they don't get discouraged. Not sure how obvious it is...